# How to I change polar projection to equirectangular?

Tags: mapping, interpolation

Specifically these maps.

https://imgur.com/a/Pvpm2Zy#dpWSjah

The image and mapping apps I have can't do want I want with the techniques I know, on the map like this.

But If I could convert it to equirectangular, it should work but I don't know how to do that. I was told to try in G.projector but it has no settings for Polar projection and the stuff I have tried to try and brute force a polar projection, don't work (set half of the map to -70ishN and 0S and 90 - 180 east to west) so any program that I can just input polar projection directly into? and how to do it?

Comment: have you tried geographiclib https://sourceforge.net/projects/geographiclib/?

Comment: No. I am downloading it now, any tips?.